# Postgres Question: Aren't both a and b correct?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

For questions below, use the following schema definition.

restaurant(rid, name, phone, street, city, state, zip)
customer(cid, fname, lname, phone, street, city, state, zip)
carrier(crid, fname, lname, lp)
delivery(did, rid, cid, tim, size, weight)
pickup(did, tim, crid)
dropoff(did, tim, crid)

It's a schema for a food delivery business that employs food carriers (carrier table).
Customers (customer table) order food from restaurants (restaurant table).
The restaurants order a delivery (delivery table); to deliver food from restaurant to customer.
The pickup table records when carrier picks up food at restaurant.
The dropoff table records when carrier drops off food at customer.

1.Find customers who have less than 5 deliveries.

a. select cid,count(*)
from delivery
group by cid
having count(*) < 5;

b. select a.cid,count(*)
from customer a
inner join delivery b
using(cid)
group by a.cid
having count(*) < 5;

c. select a.cid,count(*)
from customer a
left outer join delivery b
on a.cid=b.cid
group by a.cid
having count(*) < 5;

d. select cid,sum(case when b.cid is not null then 1 else 0 end)
from customer a
left outer join delivery b
using (cid)
group by cid
having sum(case when b.cid is not null then 1 else 0 end) < 5;

e. (write your own answer)

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not correct.  They miss customers who have had no deliveries.

The last is the best of a bunch of not so good queries.  A better version would be:

```
select c.cid, count(d.cid)
from customer c left outer join
     delivery d
     on c.cid = d.cid
group by c.cid
having count(d.cid) < 5;
```

The `sum(case)` is over kill.  And Postgres even offers a better solution than that!

```
count(*) filter (where d.cid is not null)
```

But `count(d.cid)` is still more concise.

Also note the use of meaningful table aliases.  Don't get into the habit of using arbitrary letters for tables.  That just makes queries hard to understand.

Comment: wow thanks so much for the advice! and help!!